# Retain unused factor levels in legend when using scale_*_manual

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a plot in which the fill aesthetic is mapped to an ordered factor, but some levels of the factor are not present within the data. Missing factor levels are assigned fill colours via `scale_fill_manual()`, but those fill colours are not represented by the fill legend in my plot.

I expected `drop = FALSE` in my `scale_fill_manual()` to show every level of the factor along with its fill colour, but it instead retains the levels and shows them as having missing fill colours. How can I make the legend reflect the mapping I've specified for the scale?

```r
library(ggplot2)

factor_data <- 
  data.frame(
    my_factor <- 
      factor("Level three", 
             levels = c("Level one", "Level two", "Level three", "Level four", "Level five"))
  )

fill_colours <- colorRampPalette(c("green", "white"))(5)

fill_colours
#> [1] "#00FF00" "#3FFF3F" "#7FFF7F" "#BFFFBF" "#FFFFFF"

ggplot(factor_data) +
  geom_bar(
    aes(x = 1, fill = my_factor),
    colour = "black", linewidth = 0.8) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "IMD Rank (England)",
                    values = fill_colours,
                    drop = FALSE) + 
  ggtitle("Deprivation of LLSOA")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-03-04 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to a change in `ggplot2 3.5.0` which now requires to additionally set `show.legend=TRUE` in the `geom` to show missing factor levels. See [this GH issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/5728).

```r
library(ggplot2)

packageVersion("ggplot2")
#> [1] '3.5.0'

ggplot(factor_data) +
  geom_bar(
    aes(x = 1, fill = my_factor),
    colour = "black", linewidth = 0.8,
    show.legend = TRUE
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    name = "IMD Rank (England)",
    values = fill_colours,
    drop = FALSE
  ) +
  ggtitle("Deprivation of LLSOA")
```

[image]